# ng2-toastr in angular2 - Not working?

Tags: angular

I want to use notification in my angular application. I put "ng2-toastr": "1.6.0" in package.json and clicked on restore packages in order to install ng2-toastr. After which, I imported

```
import { ToastModule } from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        UniversalModule, // Must be first import. This automatically imports BrowserModule, HttpModule, and JsonpModule too.
        FormsModule,
        ToastModule.forRoot()
    ],
```

in app.module.ts

In one of my ts file I imported

```
import { ToastsManager } from 'ng2-toastr/ng2-toastr';
```

and in constructor I added

```
 constructor(public toastr: ToastsManager, vcr: ViewContainerRef)  {
        this.toastr.setRootViewContainerRef(vcr);        
    }
```

And in of my methods, I added

```
addDetail() {  
        this.toastr.success('You are awesome!', 'Success!');
    }
```

I don't see the notification yet ! What is the reason?

Comment: Look at the console.

Comment: The console error (if there is one) could be great, or more code to know where the issue could be coming from. Personally, I'd recommend you to use the SnackBar from angular material which is easier to manipulate (good events and no ViewContainerRef to manage)

Comment: Do you have a plunkr?

Comment: I would suggest you to use this toastr https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr . I was facing the same problem with ng2 version long time ago...

Comment: I am currently using angular 2.0.0. which version of ngx-toastr and angular2-animations is good to go with Angular 2.0.0.

Answer (score 3):

I use Toaster and it looks the same except, do this this wiring with ViewContainerRef in my main app component.

Here is a github project with example: https://github.com/ipassynk/ng2-toastr-example

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'xxx-app-root',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
  })
  export class AppComponent {
    // http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/modals
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;

    public constructor(public toastr: ToastsManager, viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
      // You need this small hack in order to catch application root view container ref (ng2-bootstrap)
      this.viewContainerRef = viewContainerRef;

      // Breaking change solution for Angular v2.2.x
      // https://github.com/PointInside/ng2-toastr
      this.toastr.setRootViewContainerRef(viewContainerRef);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hello, I tried installing angular2-toaster version 3.0.1 and I included ToasterModule in app.module.ts.

Comment: when I run my application I am getting script error like Uncaught TypeError: e.map is not a function at t.parameters (http://localhost:7558/dist/vendor.js?v=KXVWLH06qqSCa7OOQfW_vUkjCsdka6xndeX-bXNcnLo:26:9625) at e.parameters (http://localhost:7558/dist/vendor.js?v=KXVWLH06qqSCa7OOQfW_vUkjCsdka6xndeX-bXNcnLo:26:12892)

Comment: added a github project with example

Comment: Eerything works fine but onclick of the button, the notification is not coming !!

Comment: I dont have animations , is that the reason?

Comment: i think so. open the developer console and see the errors.

Comment: I don't see any console errors ! If I have to try installing animations which version should I go for, I am currently using angular 2.0.0.

Comment: ohh. this is the issue. toastr @latest version is Angular 4 compatible. Either u need to update angular to 4 or use different version to toastr  -    "ng2-toastr": "1.4.1". i have two projects with Angular 4 and Angular 2 and they use toastr but there are small differences.

Comment: I am currently using "ng2-toastr": "1.6.0" , I still don't get it. I want to install animation, which version shall I install?

Comment: Can you provide the angular2 project link, I will check.

Comment: Please provide the angular2 link.

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova - How come this answer does not have upvote? Its working for me.. thanks a ton!

Comment: Thank you. People want to see angular 2 and angular 4 versions.

Comment: Was there ever a 1.6.0 resolution to this issue?

I may be experiencing something similar.. I do see the notifications but they are appearing 99% behind other components and as far as I can tell, unstyled.